# how to filter dropdown inside asp repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to filter a combobox inside a Repeater control.

I have this dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddAcademicDegree" runat="server" Width="256px"   
                            SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("EdLevel") %>' CssClass="GeneralFont" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="IDNo" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

then I want to filter the next dropdown based on what you selected in the first dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddDegree" runat="server" Width="256px" SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("DegreeID") %>' CssClass="GeneralFont" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="IDNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have this query how can I use the first dropdown to filter the second dropdown?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRIS_ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="select 0 as IDNo,'' as Description union all select code as IDNo,Description from degree order by idno" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRIS_ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"> </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

here's the whole code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrEduc" runat="server" 
                        OnItemCreated="rptrEduc_ItemCreated"  EnableViewState="False" 
                        onitemdatabound="rptrEduc_ItemDataBound" onitemcommand="rptrEduc_ItemCommand" 
                        >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table width ="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                          <tr>
                          <td width="20px"><asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdDelete" runat="server" onclick="imgEdDelete_Click" ImageUrl="~/IMAGES/delete_16x16.gif" OnClientClick='return confirm("Delete this record?");' /></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left">
                        Education:</td>
                    <td>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAcademicDegree" runat="server" Width="256px"   
                            SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("EdLevel") %>' CssClass="GeneralFont" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="IDNo" AutoPostBack="True" PropertyName="SelectedValue" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">

                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Area of Study (Major)</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMajor" runat="server" 
                            Width="260px" CssClass="GeneralFontText" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Major") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                          <tr>
                          <td></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left">

                        </td>
                    <td>
```

<%--                           
                                SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("DegreeID") %>' CssClass="GeneralFont" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="IDNo" >--%>
                                ' CssClass="GeneralFont" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="IDNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"> 
                            <%--
                                SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("Degree") %>' CssClass="GeneralFont">
                                  Masters
                                  Bachelors
                            --%>
                        
                        
                            Area of Concentration (Minor)
                        
                            '>
                        
                    
                    
                    
                        
                            *Name of Institution:
                        
                            '>*
                        
                        
                            Graduation year: 
                        
                            ' CssClass="GeneralFontText">

Comment: and where is the `asp:repeater`?

Comment: sorry forgot to paste

Comment: Not exactly solving your problem here - but why don't you make an AJAX call to get the options for the second drop down box based on the first drop down selection? It is quick, no post back, efficient and easy.